# Split String by ","

Tags: java, regex, split

I try to split a String by ",". Here is my code:

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String s = "asdf, dfdf, ,ego, goggel,";
         s.split("\\s*,\\s*")
     }
}
```

I get this as output: `["asfd", "dfdf", ,"ego", "googel"]`

But I want this: `["asdf", "dfdf", ,"ego", "googel",]`

If there is just a comma at the end (ore more) it should be splitted too.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you read the Javadocs for `split`, which tell you how to do this exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep trailing empty element, you need to specify the `limit` parameter

```
s.split("\\s*,\\s*", -1);
```

Read more on [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))  docs